# regex to get last occurrence of substring between 2 chars

Tags: python-3.x, regex, passwords

I have a problem because a password is printed out in a log. I can't control the source of the log so my only option is to do a replacement.

I have the following string `a = "http://user:password@someurl.ip.com"`
I want to replace the password with `"*****"` using a regex

something like

```
b = re.sub('(?<=:)(.*?)(?=@)', '********', a)
```

my problem is that I'm matching from the first `":"` so I'm replacing `"//user:password"` instead of `"password"`

How can I tune my regex to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rule out matching a `:` and `@` using a negated character class:

```
(?<=:)[^:@]+(?=@)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W8Kaoj/1)

```
import re
 
a = "http://user:password@someurl.ip.com"
b = re.sub('(?<=:)[^:@]+(?=@)', '********', a)
print(b)
```

Output

```
http://user:********@someurl.ip.com
```

---

Or perhaps use a bit more specific match using a capture group to match the protocol:

```
import re
 
a = "http://user:password@someurl.ip.com"
b = re.sub(r"\b(https?://[^:]+:)[^:@]+(?=@)", r"\1********", a)
print(b)
```